# avds not being listed on console

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-2.1

Im using android sdk with eclipse in fedora.
I successfully installed everything, created an virtual device from Android SDK and AVD manager, installed my app and tested on it, everything works fine.

But when i try the command
 
    "android list avds"
on my terminal, nothing shows up.

Actually i need to start the emulator and then change the hosts file on my device using the commands as in http://androidforums.com/application-development/240927-android-emulator-edit-hosts-file-doesnt-resolve-custom-domain-name.html

What am i doing wrong.?

Comment: android list avds returns list of running avd. You need to start AVD first.

Comment: @pankaj , But when i do "emulator -avd test1_avd -partition-size 128", where test1_avd is the avd i created using eclipse, and its there in the .android/avd folder, it says "ERROR: unknown virtual device name: 'test1_avd'"

Comment: Ok try to start emulator from Window -> Android SDK and AVD manager -> Vertual devices -> select AVD -> and click on Start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs to execute these commands from a user other than the root user. executing the list and emulator command from another user worked.